# Using fb-login-button div class and JQuery

Tags: c#, facebook

I have a FB login button and want to bind it to a function but I can't seem to get it work:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" id="auth-loginlink"></div>
```

This is the line that I am trying to bind it to my fb-login-button

```
$("#auth-loginlink").click(function () { grantPermission(); });

<script type="text/javascript">

    function grantPermission() {
        window.FB.login(function (response) {
          // ... login stuffs
    }

</script>
```

It will work if I use a normal hyper link like:

```
<a href="#" id="auth-loginlink"> Login</a>
```

Please kindly advice what am I doing wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it's really a button might as well use the button tag:

```
<button class="fb-login-button" id="auth-loginlink">Login</button>
```

Put your javascript inside the script tag, and return *false* in the handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#auth-loginlink").click(function () { grantPermission(); return false; });

    function grantPermission() {
        window.FB.login(function (response) {
          // ... login stuffs
    }

</script>
```

... also might be a good idea to do `$("#auth-loginlink").button()` but not totally necessary.

Note: If your html is actually *below* your javascript code the above will not always work.